# AWS CDK CfnInclude throws Error: Parameter with name 'Environment' was not found in the template

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I have a Cloudformation template with parameter defined like this

```json
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "description",
  "Parameters": {
    "Environment": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "test",
      "AllowedValues": ["test", "live"],
      "Description": "The deployment environment."
    }
  }
}
```

And I am including the same in my stack like this

```ts
export default class MainStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps, live?: boolean) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    
    const mainStack = new CfnInclude(this, 'MainStackTemplate', {
      templateFile: 'template.json',
      parameters: {
        Environment: live ? 'live' : 'test',
      },
    });
    
    const Environment: string = mainStack.getParameter('Environment').valueAsString;
  }
}
```

However, when I run `npx cdk synth` I get error

`Error: Parameter with name 'Environment' was not found in the template`

What am I doing wrong here and what is the correct way to pass the parameters to stack when including with `CfnInclude`? The docs say that all I need to do is pass the `parameters` mapping but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

The error is not triggered by the `CfnInclude` instruction; it is actually triggered by the `getParameter('Environment')` method.

This occurs because when you pass the parameter in the constructor of the CfnInclude stack, you are effectively setting that parameter. 
This replaces all the corresponding values in the template with the value you provided and then removes the parameter from the template, as indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.cloudformation_include-readme.html).

> **Parameters Replacement**
> If your existing template uses CloudFormation Parameters, you may want
> to remove them in favor of build-time values. You can do that using
> the parameters property.
> (...) 
> This will replace all references to
> MyParam with the string 'my-value', and MyParam will be removed from
> the 'Parameters' section of the resulting template.

To eliminate the error, simply delete the last line in your code.

If you want to verify the value of the `Environment` parameter, you should check a Resource where that parameter has been utilized.